# Which way is better to GET data from remote service

Tags: java, spring, http

I know there are lots of ways to `GET` the data from remotes. I have tried these different types:

1. using `curl` within a `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` or `new ProcessBuilder(...).start()`;
2. using library as `URL` or `RestTemplate`;

Are there some **significant** differences among them that we should think over before using one of them?

#### Update #0

Why I ask this seemingly **topic-too-broad** or **opinion-based** question?

I encountered an issue using `ProcessorBuilder` in a highly concurrent system, there will be some `TimeOut` while using `RestTemplate`, there is none?!

After digging and debugging, I found nothing quite related to the result and I asked this question to **understand what I might have overlooked**.

```
    List<CompletableFuture<GrafanaDashboard>> futureList = dbList.stream()
            .map(boardName -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> GrafanaRetriever
                    .parseDashboard(apiUrl, tokenString, boardName), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (CompletableFuture<GrafanaDashboard> completableFuture : futureList) {
        try {
            dashboards.add(completableFuture.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)); 
           // using ProcessorBuilder, it will hang here and some might time out (not all just some)
           // using RestTemplate, it will not wait almost, just smooth and no time out at all;
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
            log.warn("Retrieving data from grafana failed due to TimeOut most likely by {}", apiUrl);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

#### Update #1

Here is a small demo to get data using http `GET` with `cookie` for all of them:

```
public class RunTimeExecTest {
    private static String urlString = "https://www.google.com.sg";
    private static String tokenString = "your_cookie";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        getWithRunTimeExec();
        getWithProcessorBuilder();
        getUsingUrl();
        getUsingRestTemplate();
    }

    private static void getWithRunTimeExec() {
        System.out.println("Using RunTime.exec: ");
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl -v --cookie \"" + tokenString + "\" " + urlString);

            process.waitFor();
            System.out.println(IoHelper.output(process.getInputStream()));
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"curl", "-v", "--cookie", tokenString, urlString});

            process.waitFor();
            System.out.println(IoHelper.output(process.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void getWithProcessorBuilder() {
        System.out.println("Using ProcessorBuilder: ");
        try {
            Process process = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-v", "--cookie", tokenString, urlString).start();

            process.waitFor();
            System.out.println(IoHelper.output(process.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void getUsingUrl() {
        System.out.println("Using Url: ");
        try {
            URL myURL = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
            myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("cookie", tokenString);
            myURLConnection.connect();
            System.out.println(IoHelper.output(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void getUsingRestTemplate() {
        System.out.println("Using RestTemplate: ");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.add("Cookie", tokenString);
        HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(null, requestHeaders);
        ResponseEntity rssResponse = restTemplate.exchange(
                urlString,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                requestEntity,
                String.class);
        System.out.println(rssResponse.getBody());
    }
}
```

#### Update #2

What I found out:

1. Using `URL` or `RestTemplate` provided `by spring.web` can be more robust since they provided the *contract* that what they can do and what they cannot clearly;
2. In different platforms, you do not reply on the specific commands which vary dramatically;
3. Hard to maintain since it's asking a java programmer to understand more than just java;
4. Using `URL` or `RestTemplate` can handle some complicated processes that using `curl` is hard (or even impossible) to achieve;
5. Using `URL` and `RestTemplate` can leave lots of issues to the library maintainers and even can just leave them there (`RestTemplate` requires no `try{...} catch(...){...}`;

Comment: There is no straight answer for this, and it will depend on what you are trying to consume. Probably using the `URL` package will make it easier for your application to consume things, since you do not need to depend on external stuff.

Comment: It is better to use a Library like Spring and use RestTemplate, then using Runtime.... because this way your code is independent of the host environment.

Comment: @npinti Sorry I perhaps did not express myself well. What am I trying to understand are the **most** significant factors that we should consider. Actually I know the `portability` and `interface contract` and `platform` issues, even `usability` for exception handling and data parsing. But I am just quite afraid is there something also important that I **overlooked**. For example (the following is my guess): using `curl` in `exec` or `processBuilder`, read the data from `process` might be less performant.

Comment: @npinti ...following... Also `curl` in itself is quite different from `URL` using different implementation mechanism which might time out in different ways?

Answer (score 2):

Using the rest template (or another java library for http requests, even the build in java URL package) is better than using Runtime. On top of the portability which might be important later even if you don't think you will need it now there are other advantages.

The code is easier for maintain and understand (imagine a developer who doesn't understand curl -D -X -H etc.). It's easier to debug. You can involve some kind of circuit breaker for example when it takes too long and it is easier to do error handling. You can process the result during reading them etc. Basically you have the control and not some external tool.

Using the Runtime might save you from writing a few lines of code but since you are writing a java program anyway better do it the java way ;)

Answer (score 1):

For hitting a `GET` I would rather use Java. For the below reasons:

a. Curl is typically found on *nix. With Java, your code is supposedly Platform Independent. If in the future your code needs to run on windows. It will carry with it a dependency to have curl or a potential code change.

b. You can have better error handling without resorting to parsing the output of curl or its exit codes.

c. If the output from the GET API needs be parsed libraries like Spring can help you.